# PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value in

Tags: php, object, stdclass

Im getting what seems to be a common error in my php log, but cant seem to resolve based on other threads..

Im getting the error: PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in

Pointing at the following code:

```
$status = new \stdClass();

$status->about->requester       = $username;
$status->about->method          = $method;
$status->about->command         = $cmd;
```

The other posts all say to use ( $status = new \stdClass(); ) or variations of.
I've tried them all, but the error persists.

Any thoughts?

Driving me insane as the log is somewhat very big and this is my only error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not about `$status` object, but `$status->about`. Assign an instance of stdClass to it first and the error will go.

```
$status = new \stdClass();

$status->about = new \stdClass();

$status->about->requester       = 'username';
$status->about->method          = 'method';
$status->about->command         = 'cmd';
```

Comment: No, there is no error after adding such assignment. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b28669fec6e9d82f9710c60d0df66cbd6da840c

Comment: yeah im sure. :( unfortunately at this end it persists.

Even if i put your exact copy from the sandbox into a test.php file, it then shows the same error.



 php --version
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 (cli) (built: Apr  8 2020 15:45:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Well, if you say that even file that contains only the code from the sandbox still shows the error, I think you might have some custom code auto-appended due to option defined in php.ini. Try to run `php -i | grep pend` and make sure `auto_append_file` and `auto_prepend_file` are emty. Then run `php test.php`.

Comment: Nothing stands out. Its a very new install too. Like. apt installed apache2 and php.. Nothings really changed other than a few vhosts.  Sooo weird ,,  painfully weird.

Comment: Think ill just have to put this down to some oddity, clearly its an issue here. Cheers